# Transferring photos and music between Mac and iPhone

Tags: imac

I'm using a 2011 iMac running macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and an iPhone SE using version 13.1.3

I can no longer connect the two by USB or Bluetooth. Is there another was to transfer photos from the phone to the Mac and music from the Mac to the phone?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways.

A simple and popular way to copy files and share files among your devices.
https://www.dropbox.com/

"Box lets you store all of your content online, so you can access, manage and share it from anywhere. Integrate Box with Google Apps and Salesforce and access Box on mobile devices" Rated the most secure cloud storage by SkyHigh Networks.  You can buy a license to run box one of your servers.
https://www.box.com/

Using iTunes to transfer files:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4094?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
chinajon provides an explanation on how to do file transfers
https://discussions.apple.com/message/30289293#30289293

"iMazing is the all purpose iOS management software: expand your control over your mobile data beyond what is normally possible, without jailbreaking your device. With iMazing, you can easily browse and manage your backups, extract and print your text messages, or drag and drop songs to your iPhone. To put it simply, iMazing allows you to go way beyond what iTunes offers"
https://imazing.com/

Files Connect -- "Cloud Storage services like Dropbox, MobileMe iDisk, Google Docs/Picasa, Facebook photos, FTP, SFTP, WebDAV ... AFS (Apple File Shares) SMB (Windows shares)  protocols"
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/files-connect/id404324302?mt=8

Windows File server
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/filebrowser-access-files-on/id364738545?mt=8